# How to add a hidden value to DataGridView TextBox? (C#)

Tags: c#

I am working with an existing GridView and I want to know if there is a way I can have a different value and display for the TextBoxColumn, similar to a ComboBoxColumn (displaymember, valuemember).

```
private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn PATH;

 this.PATH.DataPropertyName = "Path";
 this.PATH.HeaderText = "PATH";
 this.PATH.Name = "Path";
 this.PATH.ReadOnly = true;
 this.PATH.Width = 186;
```

Right now I have a hidden column with the ID but I am wondering if there is a better solution.

ETA: I have put 
PATH.DataPropertyName = "PathId" (the hidden value I want to use for update) and this.PATH.Name = "Path" (The string value I want displayed)

The Name value is still returned when I get the value of the column.

this.mySampleGridView.Rows[i].Cells["Path"].Value

Answer (score 0):

DataPropertyName should help here, if I understand the question correctly.

From the MSDN documentation about DataGridViewColumn.DataPropertyName:

```
// Initialize and add a text box column.
DataGridViewColumn column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
column.DataPropertyName = "Name";
column.Name = "Knight";
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column);
```

The column is now bound to an item that has multiple pieces of information but is only showing one piece.  The rest is effectively hidden.

EDIT: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.datapropertyname.aspx

Comment: I have tried this using the Name property, but the value of the row still returns the Name value, and not the DataPropertyName value.

Comment: Have you tried looking at DataGridViewRow.DataBoundItem?  That should get you the underlying data item you're using.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.databounditem.aspx